# Need Suggesion on PostgreSQL Database Minor upgrade Procedure from 9.5.15 to 9.5.19:

Tags: postgresql-9.5, redhat

Thanks Alot each and every one.

Could you please help us to below points:

We are trying to deploy the latest postgres minor version 9.5.19.

We have deployed postgres server using yum repository.

Existing Version: 9.5.15
OS Platform : RHEL 7.2

target Verion: 9.5.19

What are the pre-requisities.
How  to Deploy the latest minor release.
What are the Post-Deployment activities.
What are the Rollback activities

Please share some best practices for this activity..

Comment: Just upgrade the package using the approriate `yum` command and restart the Postgres. Nothing else required

Comment: Thank you..Could you please let us know how to rollback to previous plan if we face any issues after upgrade..